# Cannot input a double. Why?

Tags: c, double

I can't scan a double to a variable.

This is my code, it is very simple. I built it with command:

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -ansi -c double.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double f;
    scanf("%lf", &f);
    printf("%lf\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Input: 5.5 (or any other numbers)

Output: 0 (always)

I am using (GCC) 4.9.3.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine in modern C (and has been fine since 1999). However, you are apparently compiling it in archaic C89/90 mode. Back then `printf` did not support `%lf` format. Note, your version is actually *preferable*, but you have to remember that historical peculiarity. The real question is: why are you compiling in archaic mode?

Comment: @AnT I didn't know that. But why gcc don't set up C99 mode by default?

Comment: GCC as finally switched to C11-based dialect of C as default one just about a month (or a few months) ago. Before that they were devotedly sticking to C89/90 for legacy code compatibility reasons or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the compiler warning and fix it.

```
~$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -ansi -c mydouble.c 
mydouble.c: In function ‘main’:
mydouble.c:5:12: warning: ISO C90 does not support the ‘%lf’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]
     printf("%lf\n", f);
```

You can change the compiler flag or change the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double f;
    scanf("%lf", &f);
    printf("%f\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using MinGW on windows, and it don't show me this warning.

Comment: @DDK Is that your first choice for a development environment? Why don't you use a development OS in VirtualBox like Linux in VirtualBox?

Comment: Yes. I think I will choose Linux for development environment, soon.